# How can I configure Vagrant to host Pyramid project on specific IP?

Tags: vagrant, pyramid

I am having good experience using Vagrant with Django, But thinks change everyday now I am working on a Pyramid project and I would love to use Vagrant but can't figure out how can i configure Vagrant to setup a vagrant environment for Pyramid.

I hope someone faced this situation and will try to help me out. :)

Thanks,

Comment: using vagrant to do what exactly?

Comment: Using Vagrant i want to host my pyramid project on specific IP.

Comment: Edited my question title.

Comment: you would do it much the same way as you would for django. they are both wsgi applications, you want to set up a wsgi application, and vagrant really has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ok, I will try and let you know.

Comment: I tried but couldn't success. I think i need to write my own chef recipe for pyramid project. but i don't have any idea how to write chef recipe for pyramid. Would you help me?